# How to get pull requests filter with owner using Github API

Tags: github-api, pull-request

I just want to query the PRs from a specific user.

Do I need to use the `head` param? But how?

`https://api.github.com/repos/org-a/repo-b/pulls?state=open&per_page=1&head=owner:user-c` does not work.

API Refer: https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests

Comment: The head param is quite poorly documented and as such is not particularly useful - I was able to get it to work in GitHub Enterprise by passing head=MyOrg:BranchName but that gave me one pull request - the pull request for that branch.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the Search API and specify `repo:REPO`, `author:USER` and `is:pr` filters:

https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues-and-pull-requests

For example, here are the pull requests from `rails/rails` from `aderyabin`:

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=is:pr+repo:rails/rails+author:aderyabin

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) syntax to query the pull requests in the repo `rails/rails` from the author `aderyabin`:

```
{
  search(query: "is:pr author:aderyabin repo:rails/rails", type: ISSUE, first: 100) {
    issueCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on PullRequest {
          title
          createdAt
          url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The [PullRequest object](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#pullrequest) docs lists the fields available to query.

It doesn't seem to be possible at the moment to filter a user's  PR for a given repo (or a repo's PR for a given user), but the same result can be achieved with the `search` query above.